# Does C# Parallel.ForEach use the same thread for iterations of the collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have an IEnumerable that I want to pass to Parallel.ForEach, but the IEnumerable is implemented using a C# method and yield, and potentially the code in enumerator is not thread safe.  Was planning to use Parallel.ForEach on this.  I am under the assumption that the actual internal iteration of the IEnumerable by ForEach is always on the same thread, and then the ForEach passes each item to a potential other thread for the processing.   Is this correct?

I read where IEnumerable iteration uses thread local storage and different threads accessing the same IEnumerable will each have their own iteration current, next, etc.  This is why I am assuming that the ForEach will actually do all the iteration on the same thread.

I at least know the iteration is not on the same thread that the Parallel.ForEach is called.  Kinda hoping it was since I need to do some thread initialization for the thread that is doing the iteration.  So may have an issue here to inject my initialization in on the thread doing the iteration.

Comment: i presume you wouldn't want to use multithreading on something that isn't thread safe.

Comment: I want the enumeration to be thread safe on a single thread, but the actual processing of the individual elements can be on multiple threads.

Comment: So, it sounds from comments that it is iterating the elements in the same thread.  Now, just wish it would have done it on the main thread, or, I guess some way to hook into it.  I will try wrapping another method with yields and see if I can initialize the thread before yielding each element

Comment: I created a function that yields each item, and put log when entered and also for each yield and I am seeing that it is called from multiple threads.  So, not called from a single thread.  Wonder if that means that my enumeration passed to the ForEach has to be thread safe.

Answer (score 6):

It's *impossible* to write an `IEnumerator` that can safely be iterated from multiple threads.  The API is inherently opposed to allowing such behavior.  Because of this Parallel.ForEach has no possible choice but to enumerate the sequence from a single thread. In order to directly expose the iterator to each of the spawned threads it would need to use a different API than what `IEnumerator`/`IEnumerable` expose.

Comment: I am not sure this is exact. One can safely enumerate from different threads as long as the MoveNext calls are synchronized and this can easily break anything that depends on thread local storage.

Comment: @Stilgar No, you couldn't enumerate an enumerator safely from multiple threads.  First off, the whole point of doing so would mean that the calls to `MoveNext` *wouldn't* be synchronized.  That's what it would mean for them to be designed to be safely enumerated from multiple threads.  Additionally, one could never be sure that the value of `Current` actually applied to the move that the thread made; you'd see two threads move the iterator at the same time, and then both use the current value of the second move.

Comment: From what I understand, if you do iterate from multiple threads, each thread will each have their own private iteration steps.  e.g. if 10 elements in the enumeration, each thread will independently iterate through each of the 10 elements (rather than one threads gets a few, another thread gets a few, etc.)

Comment: @Ron That would be multiple threads accessing a single `IEnumerable` but each using their own `IEnumerator`.  that's entirely different from multiple threads accessing a single `IEnumerator`.  `IEnumerable` objects *can* (and often are) designed to be accessed from multiple threads.  Of course it wouldn't be sensible at all for `Parallel.ForEach` to have each of its threads get an `IEnumerator` from the `IEnumerable` and each iterate the whole sequence.

Comment: @Servy, how does Parallel.ForEach guarantee that each item in the collection will only be accessed once if each thread is potentially doing the iteration.  There has to be some synchronization for the enumeration.  I just figured that the ForEach would be doing this on a single thread and then quickly passing off the iterated item to the other threads to process

Comment: @Ron It is doing all of the iteration on a single thread, that's exactly what I told you it's doing, because it couldn't possibly do the iteration from multiple threads.

Comment: I never realized this fact before. It is probably a design error of IEnumerator that it has two members. This also doubles the number of vcalls per item.

Comment: @Servy, sorry, misread your answer.  Though, I created a new function wrapper around my IEnumerable and iterate through them with yield. I log at the start of the function my threadId, and then for each loop of the yield, I log the threadId.  I am getting a range of different threadIds in the IEnumerable function that I pass to ForEach.   btw,  thanks for your timely reponses!

Comment: @usr Which part is a design error? The thread affinity or the vcalls?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it's not possible to design an internally thread-safe IEnumerable because you need two calls to get an element out. The two vcalls are a 2nd disadvantage of that design.

Comment: @usr By internally you mean making it one atomic operation?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes. You can never know what `Current` will return you in the presence of concurrent MoveNext calls.