# Iterator in a Parallel.ForEach is run on multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have some code that I run within a `Parallel.ForEach` loop. The code in the loop is thread safe, but the iterator that I'm using (a custom method with `yield return`) is not. It appears that the iterator is being run on multiple threads which could potentially cause issues.

**Background to the problem**

The iterator contains calls to NHibernate (althought that's entirely incidental as you'll see later) and as I was having issues parallelising the code I looked in NHibernate Profiler to see what if that could shine some light on the situation. Part way through it started to report "Using a single session in multiple threads is likely a bug".

Now, according to NHibernate Profiler the offending code was inside the iterator (so it wasn't trying to materialise something elsewhere in the `Parallel.ForEach` action). So I added some of my own code so that I could detect what NHibernate Profiler was and I saw the same thing.

The iterator method is being called from multiple threads - which I thought was impossible, as others seem to think also, e.g. this other SO answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26553810/8152

**Simplified demonstration of the problem**

To demonstrate the issue (without needing all my extraneous gubbins dealing with NHibernate, etc.) I wrote a simple console app that shows the same problem:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(YieldedNumbers(), (n) => { Thread.Sleep(n); });
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> YieldedNumbers()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int lastKnownThread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        int detectedSwitches = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int currentThread = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            if (lastKnownThread != currentThread)
            {
                detectedSwitches++;
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"{detectedSwitches}: Last known thread ({lastKnownThread}) is not the same as the current thread ({currentThread}).");
                lastKnownThread = currentThread;
            }
            yield return rnd.Next(100,250);
        }
    }
}
```

Of my test runs, the thread switches between 157 and 174 times in the 1000 iterations. The `Sleep` simulates the time my action takes.

**Summary**

Why does `Parallel.ForEach` do this if the iterator pattern as implemented in .NET is inherently not thread-safe? and; What would be a good solution to be able to get the data, that the iterator currently exposes, in a safe way (on one thread), yet process it on multiple threads? (e.g. Is there any way to force the iterator back onto one thread? Or must the iterator also be thread-safe as well as the action that is invoked for each iteration? Or some other solution entirely?)

*Version history*

- Updated the summary to hopefully avoid or reduce the XY Problem of my original question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to force the iterator back onto one thread?

No, you have to explicitly handle the condition where multiple threads are calling the iterator. Behind the scenes, if multiple threads are calling `IEnumerator.MoveNext()`, the iterator will keep advancing as much as it's told to. There is no implicit synchronization happening here.

[@JonSkeet blogged a while back](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/10/23/iterating-atomically/) about iterating with locking. Although I must say this looks like the XY problem to me, should you be calling `NHibernate` in parallel from multiple threads? Is it's context thread-safe at all? Those are questions you should consider before going into the wild with thread-safe iterators.

Comment: As far as I was aware, since the iterator pattern as implemented in .NET via the `IEnumerator` interface is inherently not thread-safe (the example in Jon Skeet's blog you reference shows the race condition that would occur) then I would expect that NHibernate is only being called from one thread. However, it turns out it is not if I use the iterator with `Parallel.ForEach`. So, maybe better questions are: Why does this happen? and; What would be a good solution to get the data safely (from one thread), yet process it in multiple threads?

Comment: @Colin *then I would expect that NHibernate is only being called from one thread* The exact opposite is true in this case. It's simple, the iterator is a single instance, iterated by multiple threads. There is no one thread in charge of the iteration in a "producer-consumer" like fashion. It's more like the wild west.